# Netplan can't get ipv4 address

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

First, I have to say I'm quite a noob.

I have Ubuntu Server on rpi4. I want that all my connections go through it.

I did what is explained here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109425/ubuntu-server-18-wifi-hotspot-setup (tttapa's answer), but I do not get an ipv4 address for `eth0`. Routers DHCP is disabled btw.

If I assign it manually and provide my router's IP address as gateway and nameservers, the connection only lasts a few minutes.

What I don't get is that on the Wi-Fi side, everything seems to be working as expected (`wlan0` gets an address and clients are assigned one), actually I don't really get how (i didn't set any DHCP parameters anywhere).

I've tried to play with ISC-dhcp-server a bit.

Thanks a lot.

Edit:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "Raspberry":
          password: "your password here"
          mode: ap
```

Comment: Can you include your netplan config files in your question (files are found in `/etc/netplan`)? Thanks.

Comment: Basically that's what in the link i've given, though I've tried multiple changes; I'll ad it.

Comment: There are some things I don't understand. You say "router's DHCP is disabled". How do you expect to get an IP address if DHCP is disabled? This needs to be enabled for the above config to work. Also, have you tried removing everything under the "wifis:" section, and tried just with the ethernet part of the config - and see if you get an IP address?

Comment: I don't get it neither: how wlan0 is getting an address then? I'll try what you say and tell you.

Comment: I get no ip for wlan0 as expected. I don't get no ipv4 address for eth0. I must add that in both cases i get an ipv6 address i think (line starting by inet6).

Comment: Is Network Manager installed and running on your server? If so, configure networking in the NM gui. If not, as we suspect, then your netplan file should say: `renderer: networkd` instead of NM. Please see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml`